# Using gcloud compute instances create, how can I create an empty disk and mount it automatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I can create a GCP instance and attach a disk like this:

```
gcloud compute instances create ... --create-disk size=100G
```

However, when my instance starts, the disk is not formatted or mounted. Is there a way that I can specify a filesystem and have the disk formatted and mounted using some options to the `gcloud instances create`?

I see that it is possible to specify an image family in the options --create-disk, but all I want is a disk that is formatted as, say, ext4, and using a whole disk image for that seems like overkill.

I can also of course format and mount the disk manually by ssh'ing to it, which is what I'm doing at the moment, but I would like to avoid such manual steps if possible.

Comment: You can create a script that runs at instance startup and specify that script via `--metadata startup-script` [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create). However, that script will run on each system boot, so make sure it is smart enough to not reformat your disk. For that reason, I prefer to run the script manually via SSH. You can also use tools like Terraform, Ansible, etc to automate system deployment.